# Template must have exactly one root element with custom directive replace: true

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having issues with a custom directive with replace: true,

http://jsbin.com/OtARocO/2/edit

As far as I can tell, I do only have one root element, my , what is going on here?

```
Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: 
<tbody>
  <tr><td>{{ item.name }}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row2</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("AngularApp", [])
  .directive('custom', [function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'lineItem.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  }])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    { 
      name: 'foo'
    },
    {
      name: 'bar'
    },
    {
      name: 'baz'
    }
  ];
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="description" content="Angular Avatar Example" />  

  <script src="//crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="AngularApp">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="lineItem.html">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>{{ item.name }}</td></tr>
      <tr><td>row2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </script>
  <div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table>
      <custom data-ng-repeat="item in items"></custom>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the code and the exact and complete error message here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems to be [a known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459) of AngularJs.

What you could do is to change the restriction to attribute instead of element, remove the `tbody` from the template and use a `<tbody custom ng-repeat="item in items">` in your html code.

Basically:

Your template becomes:

```
<tr><td>{{ item.name }}</td></tr>
<tr><td>row2</td></tr>
```

Your directive:

```
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: 'lineItem.html',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

  }
};
```

And your HTML :

```
<div data-ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody custom data-ng-repeat="item in items"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Watch out with comments in directive templates as well!
[docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt)

> Watch out for html comments at the beginning or end of templates, as these can cause this error as well. Consider the following template:

```
<div class='container'> 
 <div class='wrapper>
 ...
 </div> <!-- wrapper -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

> The `<!-- container -->` comment is interpreted as a second root element and causes the template to be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This error could also occur with an incorrect url to a (non-existing) template. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34284646/430885

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all the html elements that will be echoed/written to the page, have been wrapped in an envelop. i.e if my template will write a form input that has a label,input[text] and a span. Remember to wrap everything in a div.

i.e

```
<div>
<label> My Directive Label</label>
<input type='text' ng-model='xyz' />
<span ng-class='errors'></span>
</div> <!-- the root element , the element that envelops everything-->
```

Another Error you may receive may be  "Unterminated string object" which means that the template string has not been terminated properly - to solve this just include a backlash character "\" at the end of each line break i.e

```
.
.
replace:true,
restrict:'ACE',
template : "<div> \
<label> My Directive Label</label> \
<input type='text' ng-model='xyz' /> \
<span ng-class='errors'></span> \
</div> \
",....
```

Comment: Ironically enough, the trailing HTML comment in your example (`<!-- the root element , the element that envelops everything-->`) is one of the main reasons for the error that OP is describing (see other replies to this question).