# Why Props data passing between Parent to Child not working in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue.js

Here, i use some list of data in Javascript variable to pass to VueJs Template Loop.

My Javascript Variable,

```
var templates = {
                  0:{ 
                      'nb':1,
                      'column':2
                     },
                  1:{ 
                      'nb':1,
                      'column':2
                     }
              }
```

My Parent Template is,

```
   <div v-for="(te,index) in templates" class="row">
      <campaign_segment :t_nb="te.nb" :t_column=te.column>   </campaign_segment>
   </div>
```

Parent Template's Source,

```
<template v-if="showTemplate" id="segment_body">
        <b>@{{ t_nb }}</b>
        <div v-for="a in t_nb">
           <block v-if="t_column == 4 || t_column > 4"></block>  // <== Child Template,
         </div>
</template>
```

Child Template's Source,

```
    <template id="campaignBlock">
      <b>HIT</b>
    </template>
```

My VueJS,

```
  // For Parent Template
  Vue.component(
   'campaign_segment', {
   template: '#segment_body',
   props: ['t_nb', 't_column']
 });


// For Child Template
Vue.component('block', {
     template: '#campaignBlock'
});
```

In general,

```
       <div v-for="a in t_nb">
           <block v-if="t_column == 4 || t_column > 4"></block>  // <== Child Template,
         </div>
```

No loop were generated.

here, if i use,

```
        <div v-for="a in 2">
           <block v-if="t_column == 4 || t_column > 4"></block>  // <== Child Template,
         </div>
```

Loop is working fine.

Whats wrongs with this, why vuejs never uses the same instance to process the loop ?

Comment: but `t_nb` is always passed 1 as `nb` in `templates` is always 1?

Comment: @saurabh, But i get empty...
Not even single row.

If i pass "1", then i'll get one row as output !

Comment: `segment_body` should have a root element, fragments are no more supported. Did you checked your console for errors or warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is, there can be two issees:

1. Having multiple components under template, so you can put all of them in a single `div`, as is solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992470/template-for-directive-must-have-exactly-one-root-element).
2. Using `parseInt` in `v-for`, as it can be passed as a string in props instead of an integer, you can also put data type of props as explained [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Prop-Validation).

HTML

```
<template>
   <div v-if="showTemplate" id="segment_body">
        <b>@{{ t_nb }}</b>
        <div v-for="a in parseInt(t_nb)">
           <block v-if="t_column == 4 || t_column > 4"></block>  // <== Child Template,
         </div>
  </div>
</template>
```