# Template for directive must have exactly one root element : With restrict E & replace true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently maintaining a legacy AngularJS app (v1.3.8).

Why does the demo app gives me the following error?

```
Template for directive 'handleTable' must have exactly one root element.
```

### sandbox.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="sandbox.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <handle-table></handle-table>
</body>

</html>
```

### sandbox.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('handleTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: 'hello world'
    };
});
```

There's a bug being reported : [Template must have exactly one root element with custom directive replace: true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233372/template-must-have-exactly-one-root-element-with-custom-directive-replace-true) However, it seems to be only related to `table/tr/td` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use replace = true, your template must have exactly one top level element as the error mentioned.

Your angular directive template is text "hello world", which is not a html element and is treated as invalid root element.

In this case, you can try to wrap the text in a span or div:

```
app.directive('handleTable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<span>hello world</span>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Hey, this syntax is awesome! Means I can create directives on localhost!